# Getting Axios Error 404 - Cannot Register my details in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am getting Axios error 404.
Cannot Register details in mongodb database
getting error -
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
[Error 404 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCUB4.jpg)
there might also be Mongodb connection error.

1. Register.js -
   this is my frontend with axios

```
const Register = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    //form submit
    const submitHandler = async (values) => {
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            await axios.post('/users/register', values)
            message.success('Registeration Successfull')
            setLoading(false)
            navigate('/login')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setLoading(false)
            message.error('something went wrong')
        }
        console.log()
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className='register-page'>
                {loading && <Spinner />}
                <Form layout='vertical' onFinish={submitHandler}>
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                    <Form.Item label="Name" name="name">
                        <Input />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item label="Email" name="email">
                        <Input type='email' />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item label="Password" name="password">
                        <Input type='password' />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <div className='d-flex'>
                        Already Registered ? Click here to
                        <Link to="/login"> Login</Link>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Register</button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default Register
```

2)userRoute.js -
this is my backend with express router

```
const express = require('express')


const { loginController, registerController } = require('../controllers/userController')

//router object
const router = express.Router()

//routers
//POST || LOGIN
router.post('/login', loginController)

//POST || REGISTER
router.post('/register', registerController)

module.exports = router;
```

3. Server.js -

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const colors = require('colors')
const connectDb = require('./config/connectDb')
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');


//config dot env file
dotenv.config();

//call db
connectDb()

//rest object
const app = express()

//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

//routes
/*app.use(
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
  }),
);*/

app.use('/api/v1/users', require('./routes/userRoute'));


//port
const PORT = 8080 || process.env.PORT

//listen server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the endpoint you have hit in the frontend. I hope you have set the default URL in axios config.

```
await axios.post('/register', values)
```

This will hit the `/register` end-point in your server.

You need to set a `baseURL`, which will be the base-url of your backend server in which the frontend will work on.

Create an `axiosConfig.js` file in your frontend src directory.

```
//axiosConfig.js
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/";// base-url of your backend server

//can also use interceptors if needed in future.

export default axios;
```

[axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

Import the `axios` from `axiosConfig.js` in `Register.js`:

```
//Register.js

import axios from "./axiosConfig" // path to your axiosConfig file
```

Changes in `server.js`:

```
//server.js

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",// for specific origin
  })
);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*", // accessible by all origins
  })
);

//routes

const router = require('./routes/userRoute');
app.use(router);
```

`axiosConfig` and `routes` will fix your issue.

Comment: i tried it but still getting same error 404

Comment: Now i am getting -     esponse data: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /register</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Could you please share the axiosConfig file

Comment: Are you using postman to test the api's?

Comment: i dont have an axiosConfig file

Comment: no im not using postman to test the api

Comment: i have added server.js file above

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope this will fix the issue. If not ping me here.

Comment: still getting error after following above steps

Comment: Could you share the error. Still got the same error ?

Comment: Change in server.js : `const router = require('.routes/userRoute') ` instead of `app.use('/api/v1/users', require('./routes/userRoute'));` - change `app.use(router);` and check whether it works or not. This will work ig.

Comment: it worked finally

Comment: Yeah, okey fine ; )